# Python - Problema com Função e Variável

Tags: python

Bem, estou fazendo um projeto de jogo da velha em Python, mas, no VS Code está dando um erro no print de uma função e variável não usada.

Primeiro o erro da função, estou utilizando a biblioteca **colorama** que, consigo utilizar cores. Então nas primeiras linhas do código já coloquei assim:

```
import os 
import random
from colorama import Fore, Back, Style
```

Sendo dessa forma, fui fazer as primeiras variáveis com as funções:

```
jogarNovamente="s"
jogadas=0
quemJoga=2 # 1=CPU - 2=Jogador
maxJogadas=9
vit="n"
velha=[
    [" "," "," "],
    [" "," "," "],
    [" "," "," "]
```

]

```
def tela():
    global velha
    global jogadas
    os.system("cls")
    print("    0   1   2")
    print("0:  " + velha[0][0] + " | " +velha[0][1] + " | " + velha[0][2])
    print("   -----------")
    print("1:  " + velha[1][0] + " | " +velha[1][1] + " | " + velha[1][2])
    print("   -----------")
    print("2:  " + velha[2][0] + " | " +velha[2][1] + " | " + velha[2][2])
    print("Jogadas: " + Fore.GREEN + str(jogadas) + Fore.RESET)
```

"**fore**" utilizei por conta do colorama e o **.RESET** para acabar ali.

E quando vou ao terminal rodar, aparece da seguinte forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ao invés de aparacer "Jogadadas=0" na cor verde, aparece esses números. Fui até no PIP para ver se o colorama estava funcionando, e está.

No mesmo código, está dando erros de variáveis, como por exemplo na função do jogador.

```
def jogadorJoga():
global jogadas
global quemJoga
global maxJogadas
if quemJoga==2 and jogadas<maxJogadas:
    try:
        l=int(input("Linha..: "))
        c=int(input("Coluna.: "))
        while velha[1][c]!= " ":
            l=int(input("Linha..: "))
            c=int(input("Coluna.: "))
        velha[1][c]="X"
        quemJoga=1
        jogadas+=1
    except:
        print("Jogada invalida")
        os.system("pause")
        #vit="n"
```

No caso a variável **l**, quando vou no terminal dá o erro de variável não usada. E o mais incrível é que a variável **c** não está dando problema no terminal, somente a **l**.

**l= linha
c= coluna**

Pesquisei sobre e parece que tem a ver com o PyLint que não reconhece variáveis com menos de 3 caracteres, mas fui fazer até mesmo com mais de 3 e no terminal está dando o mesmo erro de variável não usada.

Sei que é uma dúvida grande, mas quem souber responder fico grato. Como dito no começo, uso a IDE Visual Studio Code.

Comment: Sobre a saída do colorama, o terminal que está utilizando para executar o script não deve ter suporte para os caracteres que definem as cores do texto. Sobre a variável não utilizada, não dá a mesma mensagem para a variável `c` porque está utilizando ela, já a `l` não, visto que no `while` você colocou o número 1 ao invés da variável.

Comment: Em relação ao terminal, pesquisei e vi que tem como configurar... Verei se há algum tipo de configuração para aparecer essas cores. E bem, eu realmente não tinha visto que ao invés de l estava o número 1, um erro bem simples que eu não estava enxergando. Coloquei l e voltou a funcionar, muito obrigado mesmo.